# Benchmarking the Total Time Taken for a record to appear in database Using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, spring-batch, benchmarking, load-testing

I have a requirement wherein I am trying to benchmark Spring Jobs. The job reads JMS messages from a queue and inserts them into a database. I want to benchmark the performance of this job by measuring the total time it takes from reading the message off the JMS queue to the time it gets inserted in the database.

I was thinking to add a While Controller and add a JDBC Request to keep polling the database till the record is available. But this gets me thinking about two things.

1. What if the processing errors out and the record never gets inserted? In that case, I need a Timeout kind of option for While Controller.
2. How does the time checking for the record to appear to calculate for the entire While Controller?

Comment: is it possible to alter the database? if yes add "readFromQueueTime" and "insertedTime" as fields and fill them with spring batch, no need for JMeter, a simple SELECT would provide the data

Answer (score 0):

If you can process raw data, then you should add Spring Batch Listeners to the Jobs, steps or each tasklet. This can be used to log the time taken for each step you want to benchmark. Example - http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-listeners-example/